# How to apply multiple inline styles to a component as props?

Tags: css, reactjs, inline-styles

I tried so many different things but nothing is working. It either breaks the application or only one style gets applied but not both at the same time.  I have a parent component that passes some styles to a child and then the child itself has some local styles as well.

Parent component:

```
<CardSettings headline="Media accounts" size={{ flex: 1 }}></CardSettings>
```

Child component CardSettings.jsx:

```
const CardSettings = (props) => {
    return (
        <div style={({ background: '#fff' }, props.size)}>
            <h2 style={styles.headline}>{props.headline}</h2>
            {props.children}
        </div>
    )
}
```

What do I do wrong here? In this case `flex: 1` gets applied but not `background: #fff`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering your `size` prop is an object you could use [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) to merge in those styles with the ones already inside that div:

```
<div style={{ background: '#fff', ...props.size }}>
  <h2 style={styles.headline}>{props.headline}</h2>
  {props.children}
</div>
```

---

**Pre-ES6 Solution:**

Alternatively you could try [Object.assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) as so:

```
<div style={Object.assign({{}, background: '#fff', props.size)}>
  <h2 style={styles.headline}>{props.headline}</h2>
  {props.children}
</div>
```

Comment: I tried this but it gives me `module build failed: SyntaxError: Unexpected token` while pointing to spread operator. Any idea why?

Comment: Have you tried removing the parenthesis? I noticed you had them in your original question.

Comment: Yeah, I copy pasted your solution. VS code is not complaining, it's in the browser. Could perhaps something be wrong with my babel settings or something? I don't see spreado perator used anywhere in this project.

Comment: Perhaps. Try my alternative solution and see what you get.

Comment: Thanks for helping but are you sure you didn't make mistake in Object.assign solution? VS code is complaining about `',' expected` for `props.size`, squiggling the dot

Comment: `<div style={Object.assign({}, { background: '#fff' }, props.size)}>
            <h2 style={styles.headline}>{props.headline}</h2>
            {props.children}</div>` this has worked for me. You should update your answer.

Comment: Strange. I managed to replicate this and get it working [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/thirsty-dream-kvzl8?file=/src/App.js) but can adjust to reflect your code for the time being.

Comment: Thanks. And yeah it is weird regarding es6 syntax not working. I will have to look into my webpack and babel settings.

Comment: Definitely do that. Good luck.